# IBM Worklight 6.2. Start eclipse test environment server from command line

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

If I'm not wrong with each new workspace a new "instance" of Liberty is configured in the folder "WorklightServerConfig" of the workspace.

Is it possible to start the worklight server from command line using those configuration files?

I have not been able to get the right "server start" command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_wl_cli_commands.html), you can use `wl start` to start the server and `wl stop` to stop it.

If you have installed Worklight Studio, you can also use the Liberty `server` command directly:

1. `cd WL_STUDIO_INSTALL_DIR/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_*/liberty/wlp/bin`
2. Set the environment variable WLP_USER_DIR to the value defined in the file `../etc/server.env` (it may be commented out).
3. Run the `server` command with arguments `start worklight`.

   - On Unix:

     ```
     env WLP_USER_DIR=ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE/WorklightServerConfig ./server start worklight
     ```
   - On Windows:

     ```
     set WLP_USER_DIR=ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE/WorklightServerConfig
     server start worklight
     ```